# Get Users and Groups from tac_plus file

Tags: python, linux

I've been tasked to get users and groups from tac_plus file which is in our Linux environment.
The person before me created a python script which isn't working anymore and i'm not a python person myself.

The script basically used to output Users First Name and Last Name as well as access group

---

Below is the script that was created by the person. If anyone can shed some light that would be much appreshiated

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# v0.1 read_tacacs.py
# Read tac_plus.cfg file and grep username/full_name/access type into column list.

from datetime import datetime

i = datetime.now()

user_name = []
full_name = []
group_access = []


with open('/usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg', 'r') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
                if 'user =' in line:
                        user_name.append(line.split()[2])
                if 'Full Name:' in line:
                        full_name.append(line.split()[3]+ ' ' + line.split()[4])
                if 'member' in line:
                        if '@all' in line:
                                line = line.split()[2]
                                group_access.append(line.replace("@all",""))
                                #group_access.append(line)
                                #group_access.append(line.split()[2])

print '{0:20} {1:25} {2}'.format('TACACSID','Full Name', 'Access')

for x in range(len(user_name)):
        print '{0:20} {1:25} {2}'.format(user_name[x], full_name[x], group_access[x])

print '\nDate Generated: ' + i.strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S')

searchfile.closed
```

---

Below is the error i get.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./read_tacacs.py", line 20, in 
    full_name.append(line.split()[3]+ ' ' + line.split()[4])
IndexError: list index out of range

---

Any help would be much appreshiated

Thank you in advance

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

it means that line match "'Full Name:' " in the file /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg, may not contain either 3rd row or 4th row element. you may need check file /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg for investigate.